# Insert an image in xcode (cocoa app)

Tags: image, cocoa

That seems weird but i don't find anything about an equivalent of UIImageView for Mac app.
How to add an image? I've taken a look on IKImageView but I don't understand anything

Thanks for your help

Comment: maybe NSImageView http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out `NSImageView`.

[reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageView_Class/)